# SQL Server Merge, how to subset target by date range (year)

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, subset

I have been reading up on the MERGE syntax in SQL Server and it's perfect for what I need it to do, however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to prevent the target table from deleting old data that I don't want to match against.

I have 11 million rows in Target, and I only want to match current year for changes which is around ~300k rows. Obviously will be massive performance difference.

My code:

```
    MERGE  [dbo].[RE_Gifts_Backup_testing] as Target   --[TARGET is main table]
    USING  [dbo].[RE_Gifts_CY_Changes] as Source  --[SOURCE is data with new changes]

    ON (Target.gift_id = Source.gift_id)  -- What are we matching rows on.




    --When rows are matched, update the records if there is any change

    WHEN MATCHED
            AND year(Target.gift_date) = '2016'
            AND year(Source.Gift_Date) = '2016' 
            AND (TARGET.[Constituent_ID] <> SOURCE.[Constituent_ID]
            OR  TARGET.[RE_Gift_ID] <> SOURCE.[RE_Gift_ID] 
            OR  TARGET.[Gift_ID] <> SOURCE.[Gift_ID] 
            OR  TARGET.[Gift_Date_Added] <> SOURCE.[Gift_Date_Added] 
            OR  TARGET.[Gift_Date] <> SOURCE.[Gift_Date] 
            OR  TARGET.[Name] <> SOURCE.[Name] 
            OR  TARGET.[Gift_Type] <> SOURCE.[Gift_Type] 
            OR  TARGET.[Gift_Amount] <> SOURCE.[Gift_Amount] 
            OR  TARGET.[Frequency] <> SOURCE.[Frequency] 
            OR  TARGET.[Pay_Method] <> SOURCE.[Pay_Method]
            OR  TARGET.[Appeal] <> SOURCE.[Appeal]
            OR  TARGET.[Campaign] <> SOURCE.[Campaign]
            OR  TARGET.[Gift Added By] <> SOURCE.[Gift Added By]
            OR  TARGET.[Gift Reference] <> SOURCE.[Gift Reference]
            OR  TARGET.[SoftCredit] <> SOURCE.[SoftCredit]
            OR  TARGET.[Relationship Manager] <> SOURCE.[Relationship Manager]
            OR  TARGET.[CostCentre] <> SOURCE.[CostCentre] 
            OR  TARGET.[Recruiter] <> SOURCE.[Recruiter] 
            OR  TARGET.[Sitecode] <> SOURCE.[Sitecode] 
            OR  TARGET.[Zerodebit] <> SOURCE.[Zerodebit] 
            OR  TARGET.[Donation_Channel] <> SOURCE.[Donation_Channel] 
            OR  TARGET.[Source_Channel] <> SOURCE.[Source_Channel] 
            OR  TARGET.[Recruitment_Source] <> SOURCE.[Recruitment_Source] 
            OR  TARGET.[Merch_ProductID] <> SOURCE.[Merch_ProductID] )


        THEN UPDATE 
            set 
              TARGET.[Constituent_ID] = SOURCE.[Constituent_ID],
              TARGET.[RE_Gift_ID] = SOURCE.[RE_Gift_ID],
              TARGET.[Gift_ID] = SOURCE.[Gift_ID], 
              TARGET.[Gift_Date_Added] = SOURCE.[Gift_Date_Added], 
              TARGET.[Gift_Date] = SOURCE.[Gift_Date], 
              TARGET.[Name] = SOURCE.[Name],
              TARGET.[Gift_Type] = SOURCE.[Gift_Type],
              TARGET.[Gift_Amount] = SOURCE.[Gift_Amount],
              TARGET.[Frequency] = SOURCE.[Frequency],
              TARGET.[Pay_Method] = SOURCE.[Pay_Method],
              TARGET.[Appeal] = SOURCE.[Appeal],
              TARGET.[Campaign] = SOURCE.[Campaign],
              TARGET.[Gift Added By] = SOURCE.[Gift Added By],
              TARGET.[Gift Reference] = SOURCE.[Gift Reference],
              TARGET.[SoftCredit] = SOURCE.[SoftCredit],
              TARGET.[Relationship Manager] = SOURCE.[Relationship Manager],
              TARGET.[CostCentre] = SOURCE.[CostCentre],
              TARGET.[Recruiter] = SOURCE.[Recruiter],
              TARGET.[Sitecode] = SOURCE.[Sitecode],
              TARGET.[Zerodebit] = SOURCE.[Zerodebit],
              TARGET.[Donation_Channel] = SOURCE.[Donation_Channel],
              TARGET.[Source_Channel] = SOURCE.[Source_Channel],
              TARGET.[Recruitment_Source] = SOURCE.[Recruitment_Source],
              TARGET.[Merch_ProductID] = SOURCE.[Merch_ProductID]

    -- when no records are matched then insert from source into target.
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET and year(target.gift_date) >= '2016' THEN 

    INSERT ([Constituent_ID],[RE_Gift_ID],[Gift_ID],[Gift_Date_Added],[Gift_Date],[Name],[Gift_Type],[Gift_Amount],[Frequency],[Pay_Method],[Appeal],[Campaign],[Gift Added By],[Gift Reference],
                [SoftCredit],[Relationship Manager],[CostCentre],[Recruiter],[Sitecode],[Zerodebit],[Donation_Channel],[Source_Channel],[Recruitment_Source],[Merch_ProductID])

    VALUES (source.[Constituent_ID],source.[RE_Gift_ID],source.[Gift_ID],source.[Gift_Date_Added],source.[Gift_Date],source.[Name],source.[Gift_Type],source.[Gift_Amount],source.[Frequency],
                source.[Pay_Method],source.[Appeal],source.[Campaign],source.[Gift Added By],source.[Gift Reference],source.[SoftCredit],source.[Relationship Manager],source.[CostCentre],
                source.[Recruiter],source.[Sitecode],source.[Zerodebit],source.[Donation_Channel],source.[Source_Channel],source.[Recruitment_Source],source.[Merch_ProductID])

    --When there is a row that exists in target table and same record does not exist in source table then delete this record from target table
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE and year(target.gift_date) >= '2016' THEN 
    DELETE

    OUTPUT $action, 
            deleted.[Constituent_ID] as [deletedConstituent_ID],
            deleted.[RE_Gift_ID] as [deletedRE_Gift_ID],
            deleted.[Gift_ID] as [deletedGift_ID], 
            deleted.[Gift_Date_Added] as [deletedGift_Date_Added], 
            deleted.[Gift_Date] as [deletedGift_Date], 
            deleted.[Name] as [deletedName],
            deleted.[Gift_Type] as [deletedGift_Type],
            deleted.[Gift_Amount] as [deletedGift_Amount],
            deleted.[Frequency] as [deletedFrequency],
            deleted.[Pay_Method] as [deletedPay_Method],
            deleted.[Appeal] as [deletedAppeal],
            deleted.[Campaign] as [deletedCampaign],
            deleted.[Gift Added By] as [deletedGift Added By],
            deleted.[Gift Reference] as [deletedGift Reference],
            deleted.[SoftCredit] as [deletedSoftCredit],
            deleted.[Relationship Manager] as [deletedRelationship Manager],
            deleted.[CostCentre] as [deletedCostCentre],
            deleted.[Recruiter] as [deletedRecruiter],
            deleted.[Sitecode] as [deletedSitecode],
            deleted.[Zerodebit] as [deletedZerodebit],
            deleted.[Donation_Channel] as [deletedDonation_Channel],
            deleted.[Source_Channel] as [deletedSource_Channel],
            deleted.[Recruitment_Source] as [deletedRecruitment_Source],
            deleted.[Merch_ProductID] as [deletedMerch_ProductID],

            inserted.[Constituent_ID] as [insertedConstituent_ID],
            inserted.[RE_Gift_ID] as [insertedRE_Gift_ID],
            inserted.[Gift_ID] as [insertedGift_ID], 
            inserted.[Gift_Date_Added] as [insertedGift_Date_Added], 
            inserted.[Gift_Date] as [insertedGift_Date], 
            inserted.[Name] as [insertedName],
            inserted.[Gift_Type] as [insertedGift_Type],
            inserted.[Gift_Amount] as [insertedGift_Amount],
            inserted.[Frequency] as [insertedFrequency],
            inserted.[Pay_Method] as [insertedPay_Method],
            inserted.[Appeal] as [insertedAppeal],
            inserted.[Campaign] as [insertedCampaign],
            inserted.[Gift Added By] as [insertedGift Added By],
            inserted.[Gift Reference] as [insertedGift Reference],
            inserted.[SoftCredit] as [insertedSoftCredit],
            inserted.[Relationship Manager] as [insertedRelationship Manager],
            inserted.[CostCentre] as [insertedCostCentre],
            inserted.[Recruiter] as [insertedRecruiter],
            inserted.[Sitecode] as [insertedSitecode],
            inserted.[Zerodebit] as [insertedZerodebit],
            inserted.[Donation_Channel] as [insertedDonation_Channel],
            inserted.[Source_Channel] as [insertedSource_Channel],
            inserted.[Recruitment_Source] as [insertedRecruitment_Source],
            inserted.[Merch_ProductID] as [insertedMerch_ProductID],

            updated.[Constituent_ID] as [updatedConstituent_ID],
            updated.[RE_Gift_ID] as [updatedRE_Gift_ID],
            updated.[Gift_ID] as [updatedGift_ID], 
            updated.[Gift_Date_Added] as [updatedGift_Date_Added], 
            updated.[Gift_Date] as [updatedGift_Date], 
            updated.[Name] as [updatedName],
            updated.[Gift_Type] as [updatedGift_Type],
            updated.[Gift_Amount] as [updatedGift_Amount],
            updated.[Frequency] as [updatedFrequency],
            updated.[Pay_Method] as [updatedPay_Method],
            updated.[Appeal] as [updatedAppeal],
            updated.[Campaign] as [updatedCampaign],
            updated.[Gift Added By] as [updatedGift Added By],
            updated.[Gift Reference] as [updatedGift Reference],
            updated.[SoftCredit] as [updatedSoftCredit],
            updated.[Relationship Manager] as [updatedRelationship Manager],
            updated.[CostCentre] as [updatedCostCentre],
            updated.[Recruiter] as [updatedRecruiter],
            updated.[Sitecode] as [updatedSitecode],
            updated.[Zerodebit] as [updatedZerodebit],
            updated.[Donation_Channel] as [updatedDonation_Channel],
            updated.[Source_Channel] as [updatedSource_Channel],
            updated.[Recruitment_Source] as [updatedRecruitment_Source],
            updated.[Merch_ProductID] as [updatedMerch_ProductID];



    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
    GO
```

this throws an error:

> Msg 5334, Level 16, State 2, Line 86
>   The identifier 'target.gift_date' cannot be bound. Only target columns and columns in the clause scope are allowed in the 'WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE' clause of a MERGE statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a full script that demonstrates how I'd do it. Checked in SQL Server 2008.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @TDst TABLE (ID int, dt date, DataValue int);
DECLARE @TSrc TABLE (ID int, dt date, DataValue int);

INSERT INTO @TDst (ID, dt, DataValue) VALUES
 (11, '2015-01-01', 1100) -- don't delete
,(12, '2015-02-02', 1200) -- don't delete
,(21, '2016-01-01', 2100) -- this should be deleted
,(22, '2016-02-02', 2200) -- this would remain as is
,(23, '2016-03-03', 2300) -- this would be updated
;

INSERT INTO @TSrc (ID, dt, DataValue) VALUES
 (22, '2016-02-02', 2200) -- same date and value, don't update
,(23, '2016-03-03', 2388) -- update
,(24, '2016-04-04', 2488) -- add
;

SELECT * FROM @TDst;

+----+------------+-----------+
| ID |     dt     | DataValue |
+----+------------+-----------+
| 11 | 2015-01-01 |      1100 |
| 12 | 2015-02-02 |      1200 |
| 21 | 2016-01-01 |      2100 |
| 22 | 2016-02-02 |      2200 |
| 23 | 2016-03-03 |      2300 |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

**Query**

```
MERGE INTO @TDst AS Dst
USING @TSrc as Src
ON (Dst.ID = Src.ID)

--When rows are matched, update the records if there is any change
WHEN MATCHED
    AND (Dst.dt <> Src.dt 
    OR Dst.DataValue <> Src.DataValue)
THEN 
UPDATE 
SET
     Dst.dt = Src.dt
    ,Dst.DataValue = Src.DataValue

-- when no records are matched then insert from source into target.
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (ID, dt, DataValue)
VALUES (Src.ID, Src.dt, Src.DataValue)

-- When there is a row that exists in target table and 
-- same record does not exist in source table then delete this record from target table
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND Dst.dt >= '2016-01-01' THEN 
DELETE
;

SELECT * FROM @TDst;
```

**Result**

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| ID |     dt     | DataValue |
+----+------------+-----------+
| 11 | 2015-01-01 |      1100 |
| 12 | 2015-02-02 |      1200 |
| 22 | 2016-02-02 |      2200 |
| 23 | 2016-03-03 |      2388 |
| 24 | 2016-04-04 |      2488 |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

As you can see the data before 2016 was preserved, but data in 2016 was replaced.

If your `Source` table has data only from 2016, then you need to add extra filter `>= '2016-01-01'` only to the `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` clause to prevent deleting rows prior to 2016.

---

The error that you are getting is most likely caused by the following extra filter, which is not needed:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET and year(target.gift_date) >= '2016'
```

Comment: thanks Vladimir, that helped. Turns out that last line you identified was the issue as I was listing Target where it should have been source.